# django-registration passing extra_context to Registration Form

Tags: python, django

I've just switched to using django-registration to manage user authentication on my website. Before, I used views for the register and login pages, and so was able to specify context parameters. But now, I no longer have views for these pages, as django-registration takes care of this for me. I still need to pass the context variables though, so I've tried this:

urls.py:

```
import registration
from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView
...
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', { 'extra_context' : {'design_form': True }}),
(r'^accounts/register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationForm), { 'extra_context' : {'design_form': True }}),
(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

The 'design_form' parameter functions correctly on the accounts/login/ page but does not get passed to the registration page. How do I pass extra_context to my registration page?

Using django 1.5 and django-registration 1.0

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified - Django 1.5, django-registration 1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As RegistrationForm is descendant of `django.views.generic.FormView` and in turn of `django.generic.views.View`, passing `extra_content` is done by [overriding `get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context), example included.

> Function-based generic views provided an `extra_context` argument as way
>   to insert extra items into the context at time of rendering.
>
> Class-based views don’t provide an extra_context argument. Instead,
>   you subclass the view, overriding `get_context_data()`.

Comment: Thanks. I used `class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(MyRegistrationView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context.update({
             'design_form': True,
         })
         return context` and it works. But I'm still not sure how to pass parameters to django-registration's registration_success page and others as they are functions of the RegistrationView class..?

Comment: Also would be nice to link that question here for follow ups.