# Django-registration class-based views with different templates and parameters

Tags: python, django

Following [django-registration passing extra_context to Registration Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864048/django-registration-passing-extra-context-to-registration-form/19864387?noredirect=1#comment29548159_19864387) , I have been able to send extra contexts to the django-registration Registration Form but not to the other pages of django-registration, like the registration_success page and the activation_complete page.

All I want to do is pass one parameter to each of these django-registration to tell them how to display. But how to do this does not seem clear to me.

At the moment this is part of my `urls.py`:

```
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', { 'extra_context' :     {'design_form': True }}),
(r'^accounts/register/complete/$', OneBoxView.as_view()),
(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationForm)),
(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

So, for instance, the register/complete page uses the OneBoxView classed based view, which looks like this:

```
class OneBoxView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'registration/registration_complete.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(OneBoxView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context.update({
                'design_onebox': True,
            })
```

But this view function has a single template, and I can't find how to get the individual django-registration pages to pass a template to the class. Setting up a class-based view means that the source code (`direct_to_template,
                           {'template': 'registration/registration_complete.html'},`) fails to work.

I don't want to write separate view functions for each of the urls, and writing a big 'if' function or `% self.kwargs['template']` to grab the name of the page seems to be inelegant too. There must be some elegant way for most of the pages of django-registration to simply be passed a "design_onebox" parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable template name can be passed to a `TemplateView` class in two ways:

- redefining `get_template_names` method

> Returns a list of template names to be used for the request. Must return a list. May not be called if render_to_response is overridden.

- passing template_name to `as_view` method:

```
TemplateView.as_view(template_name='some_template_name')
```

Last option is to overwrite `get_success_url` method of `RegistrationView` class, which by default is simply (omitting docstring)

```
def get_success_url(self, request, user):
    return ('registration_complete', (), {})
```

But from your question I can't guess where from `template_name` have to be passed.